# Empty date field goes to 1/1/1900 when updating target list with workflow

Tags: workflow, date-time

Say, I have a `SourceList` with date fields like these `DateReceived`, `DateEntered`. If these field or fields are null then in workflow updates the target list item with 1/1/1900 dates respectively.

What's the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `1/1/1900` is SQL Server's default value for datetime.
For overcome this problem, you can check the value and if it is empty use `SqlDateTime.Null` instead of `null`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateVar))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateVar);
}
else
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SqlDateTime.Null);
}
```